# trait providing the Manifest to another trait

Tags: scala, manifest, traits

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
trait BaseMongoDAO[T <: IdentifiableModel with CaseClass] {


  implicit val manifest: Manifest[T]

  ........ some implicit manifest usage here
}


trait MongoUserRepository extends BaseMongoDAO[User] with UserRepository {

  override val manifest = Manifest.classType(User.getClass)

  ........ implementing UserRepository here

}
```

But it doesn't seem to work and it says my Manifest is of incompatible type.

I did something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we look at the definition of `classType`:

```
def classType[T](clazz: Predef.Class[_]): Manifest[T] =
    new ClassTypeManifest[T](None, clazz, Nil)
```

We can see that `T` is not inferred from the argument, and thus can only be inferred from the return type, or by explicitly giving the type parameter. The following should fix your issue:

```
override val manifest = Manifest.classType[User](User.getClass)
```

Alternatively:

```
override val manifest: Manifest[User] = Manifest.classType(User.getClass)
```